# Can't fetch data from relation table in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I am try to get data from the other table by seting the relation I don't get a value

```
$customersFeedbackList = \App\coustomer_feedback::all();

foreach($customersFeedbackList as $feedback){

    echo ($feedback->coustomer_id);
    echo ($feedback->customer['name']);
}
```

here is my model

Comment: class customer extends Model
{
    //
    public function customer_feedback()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\coustomer_feedback');
    }
}

Comment: class coustomer_feedback extends Model
{
    //
    public function customer_feedback()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\customer');
    }
}

Comment: Please ask an actual question. Please also add code to your post using the "edit" button instead of putting them without formatting into comments

Comment: can you show your related model ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, correct the spelling of <s>***coustomer_feedback***</s> in all of your code. ***customer*** is correct one.
To get customer_feedback information use this code:

```
$customer = new App\customer;

$customersFeedbackList  = $customer->customer_feedback()->get();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::coustomer_feedback()"

Comment: public function report(){

        $customer = new customer;

        $customersFeedbackList  = $customer->coustomer_feedback()->get();

        foreach($customersFeedbackList as $feedback){
       echo ($feedback->customer['name']);
    }

Comment: correct **_customer\_feedback_** in all of your code. model and controller. @souravdas

Comment: i drop my migration file and recreated it